# Implementing JWT acess and receiving Forbidden with all set up

Tags: java, authentication, spring-security, jwt, roles

I'm building a login and register application with java and spring boot version 3.1.1, I implemented the entities:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String userName;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private LocalDate registrationDate;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "users_roles",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
    private Boolean locked = false;
    private Boolean enabled = true;

    public User(String firstName, String lastName, String userName, String email, String password) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.registrationDate = LocalDate.now();
    }
}

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Role {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "role_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private UserRole roleName;
}

public enum UserRole {
    WAITER,
    KITCHEN,
    CASHIER,
    ADMIN;
}

@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class AppUserDetails implements UserDetails {

    private final User user;

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
        user.getRoles().forEach(role -> {
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getRoleName().name()));
        });
        return authorities;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return user.getPassword();
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return user.getUserName();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return !user.getLocked();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return user.getEnabled();
    }
}

@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class UserService implements UserDetailsService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        return new AppUserDetails(userRepository.findByUserName(username).orElseThrow(() ->
                new UsernameNotFoundException(String.format("User %s not found", username))));
    }
}
```

And the JWT filter, configurations and so on:

```
@Service
public class JwtService {

    @Value("${api.security.token.secret}")
    private String secretKey;

    public String extractUsername(String token) {
        return extractClaim(token, Claims::getSubject);
    }

    public <T> T extractClaim(String token, Function<Claims, T> claimsResolver) {
        final Claims claims = extractAllClaims(token);
        return claimsResolver.apply(claims);
    }

    public String generateTokens(UserDetails userDetails) {
        return generateToken(new HashMap<>(), userDetails);
    }

    public String generateToken(Map<String, Object> extraClaims, UserDetails userDetails) {
        return Jwts.builder()
                .setClaims(extraClaims)
                .setSubject(userDetails.getUsername())
                .setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .setExpiration(new Date((System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000 * 60 * 24)))
                .signWith(getSignInKey(), SignatureAlgorithm.HS256)
                .compact();
    }

    public boolean isTokenValid(String token, UserDetails userDetails) {
        final String username = extractUsername(token);
        return (username.equals(userDetails.getUsername())) && !isTokenExpired(token);
    }

    private boolean isTokenExpired(String token) {
        return extractExpiration(token).before(new Date());
    }

    private Date extractExpiration(String token) {
        return extractClaim(token, Claims::getExpiration);
    }

    private Claims extractAllClaims (String token) {
        return Jwts.parserBuilder().setSigningKey(getSignInKey()).build().parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();
    }

    private Key getSignInKey() {
        byte [] keysBytes = Decoders.BASE64.decode(secretKey);
        return Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(keysBytes);
    }
}

@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final JwtService jwtService;
    private final UserService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(@NonNull HttpServletRequest request, @NonNull HttpServletResponse response, @NonNull FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        final String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        final String jwt;
        final String userName;

        if (authHeader == null || !authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }

        jwt = authHeader.substring(7);
        userName = jwtService.extractUsername(jwt);

        if (userName != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
            UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(userName);
            if (jwtService.isTokenValid(jwt, userDetails)) {
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken =
                        new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                authenticationToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticationToken);
            }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfigurations {

    private final JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthFilter;
    private final AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authorizeHttpRequests(
                        authorize -> authorize
                                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/v*/auth/register").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "CASHIER")
                                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/v*/auth/authenticate").permitAll()
                                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .build();
    }
}
```

Everytime I try to authenticate the token is generated with success:

```
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping(path = "/api/v1/auth")
public class AuthenticationController {
    
    private final AuthenticationService authenticationService;

    @PostMapping("/register")
    @PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('ADMIN', 'CASHIER')")
    public ResponseEntity<AuthenticationResponse> register(@RequestBody RegistrationRequest request) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(authenticationService.register(request), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    @PostMapping("/authenticate")
    public ResponseEntity<AuthenticationResponse> authenticate(@RequestBody AuthenticationRequest request) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(authenticationService.authenticate(request), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AuthenticationService {

    private final JwtService jwtService;
    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    private final RolesRepository rolesRepository;
    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    public AuthenticationResponse register(RegistrationRequest request) {
        User user = new User(
                request.getFirstName(),
                request.getLastName(),
                request.getUserName(),
                request.getEmail(),
                passwordEncoder.encode(request.getPassword())
        );

        request.getRoles().forEach(role -> user.getRoles().add(rolesRepository.findByRoleName(role).orElseThrow(
                () -> new NoSuchElementException(String.format("Role %s was not found at database", role.name()))
        )));

        userRepository.save(user);
        return AuthenticationResponse.builder().token("Testando assim").build();
    }

    // TODO add some errors to return message to user
    // TODO add a constraint into username field
    public AuthenticationResponse authenticate(AuthenticationRequest request) {
        authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(request.getUsername(), request.getPassword()));

        User user = userRepository.findByUserName(request.getUsername()).orElseThrow(
                () -> new NoSuchElementException(String.format("Username %s not found", request.getUsername())));

        var jwtToken = jwtService.generateTokens(new AppUserDetails(user));
        return AuthenticationResponse.builder().token(jwtToken).build();
    }
}
```

I registered a User directly at database with the admin role, but when I try to register another user at the system using the admin user generated token at the authenticate method, I receive the 403 message forbidden with not even acessing the register method, there is something I missed?

I can make the repository public and post the link if will be better.

Added the requests. Login to get the token:

[image: login]

Setting the bearer token at the request header for register:

[image: auth]

[image: register-authorization]

Request body with the message:

[image: request-body]

Properties printscreen:

[image: properties]

Spring return for the method:

[image: intellij-screen]

Return without @PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('ADMIN', 'CASHIER')") and with .permitAll():

[image: return-succed]

Comment: can you show the request you are sending and response, screenshot of postman if possible

Comment: Added the images @AhmedNabil

Comment: I am sorry, can you add this line to application.properties "server.error.include-message=always" and show stack trace of the error

Comment: I already added it before

Comment: where is the stack trace of spring ?

Comment: It does not print nothing :(

Comment: I will change it into a .yml file to see if logs someting

Comment: this doesn't matter :D (yaml and properties do the same)

Comment: Does it just not authorize the request?

Comment: I think it's because something is not right with Roles configs, try removing the hasRole and preAuthorize to make sure everything else is right

Comment: Yes, with the @PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('ADMIN', 'CASHIER')") removed and with .permitAll() at this method matcher, worked fine, posting the return.

Comment: this could've something to do with your jwt generating you can check your jwt using this website https://jwt.io/ and this repo has almost the same code as yours, you can compare them and find what you got wrong https://github.com/ahmd-nabil/spring-security6-demo

Comment: The user at the token is the same decompiled in the website, I'll try to redo all the implementation step by step and see if I miss something.

Comment: It worked!!! I finally found it!

Comment: just remember, using JWTs as sessions is a security risk and makes your application susceptible for XSS attacks. JWTs were never meant to be used as sessions https://developer.okta.com/blog/2017/08/17/why-jwts-suck-as-session-tokens read the owasp guidelines https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/JSON_Web_Token_for_Java_Cheat_Sheet.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After a long search and documentation reading I finally find out what was my issue. I mapped the entities and the roles just by the prefixes '**ADMIN**', '**CASHIER**', ... But when using the function `hasAnyRoles`, the role should have the prefix role in their names like '**ROLE_ADMIN**', '**ROLE_CASHIER**' and not just the name. But there already is a method to use without the prefixes '**ROLE**', the `hasAuthority` method works with just the names!

So the solution was change the way I was mapping the chain filter method:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfigurations {

    private final JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthFilter;
    private final AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authorizeHttpRequests(
                        authorize -> authorize
                                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/v*/auth/register").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN", "CASHIER")
                                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/v*/auth/authenticate").permitAll()
                                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .build();
    }
}
```

In this example I used the correct method for the approach. And worked fine!

[image: success]